# Selecting a particular value of log c, complex log, so that the branch is entire?

Tags: complex-analysis

Multple-valued function $c^z$ , where c is a nonzero constant, is given by $c^z$ = e^(zlogc). Show that by selecting a particular value of log c we obtain a branch that is entire. Find the derivative of such a branch.

I'm also confused as to what this question is asking, doesn't log functions always have a branch cut, how can we find a branch such that the log function will be entire then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that here you're taking just one $c$.  $e^{az}$ is an entire function of $z$ for any complex number $a$; in particular take $a$ to be any version of $\log c$.

Comment: Awesome thanks!